# How do I search for a string in a cell substring containing a string from another cell in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am looking to compare the results of 2 cells in the same row. the way the data is structured is essentially this:

```
Col_A: table,row,cell   
Col_B: row
```

What I want to do is compare when Col_A 'row' is the same as Col_B 'row'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Col_A CONTAINS Col_B;
```

sample data:

```
Col_A: a=befd-47a8021a6522,b=7750195008,c=prof    
Col_B: b=7750195008

Col_A: a=bokl-e5ac10085202,b=4478542348,c=pedf
Col_B: b=7750195008
```

I am looking to return the number of times the comparison between Col_A 'b' and Col_B 'b' is true.

Comment: It might be beneficial if you could supply sample data and desired results.

Comment: `select * from MyTable where col_a IN (col_b)`

Comment: What would be the result you desire? Something like: `1` Its not clear if you want to know only if there is Col_B value within Col_A value like your sample data OR if you want to know how many times Col_B values appear in Col_A value. Please clarify.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I am want to count the number of times this comparison is successful in the table. I have posted an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what I was looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Col_A LIKE CONCAT('%',Col_B,'%');
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. So please accept it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I see You answered Your own question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Col_A LIKE CONCAT('%',Col_B,'%');
```

is good from performance perspective. While normalization is **very** good idea, it would not improve speed much in this particular case. We must simply scan all strings from table. Question is, if the query is always correct. It accepts for example

```
Col_A: a=befd-47a8021a6522,ab=7750195008,c=prof    
Col_B: b=7750195008
```

or

```
Col_A: a=befd-47a8021a6522,b=775019500877777777,c=prof    
Col_B: b=7750195008
```

this may be a problem depending on the data format. Solution is quite simple

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE CONCAT(',',Col_A,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',Col_B,',%');
```

But this is not the end. String in LIKE is interpreted and if You can have things like % in You data You have a problem. This should work on mysql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',',Col_B,','), CONCAT(',',Col_A,','))>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col_A = Col_B (AND Col_A = 'cell')
```

^^ Maybe you are looking for this statement. The part in brackets is optional.
If this is not the solution, please supply us with further information.

Answer (score 0):

If column Col_a has data with format **table,row,cell** then search expression will be next:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable AS MT
WHERE SUBSTRING(Col_A, 
                INSTR(Col_A, ',b=') + 3, 
                INSTR(Col_A, ',c=') - INSTR(Col_A, ',b=') + 3) = Col_B
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Col_A IN (Col_B);
```

More info on the IN operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

There's also the `SUBSTRING()`  or `MID()` (depending on what you're using) function if you know that the substring will be in the same position everytime.

MID()/SUBSTRING() function: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract a delimited field from a column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col_B = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col_A, ',', 2), ',', -1)
```

You need to call it twice to get a single field. The inner call gets the first two fields, the outer call gets the last field of that.

Note that this will be **very** slow if the table is large, because it's not possible to index substrings in MySQL. It would be much better if you normalized your schema so each field is in a separate column.